# MySQL LIke statement - multiple words

Tags: mysql

What would be the right SQL statement so that when I search two words, like for example 'text field' in a text box, it will return all results that has 'text' and 'field' in it using the LIKE statement? I cant find the right terms to make a search. If possible, I want to make it dynamic. Like if a user search 5 words, all 5 words would be in the Like statement. I am trying to achieve a statement something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE SEARCH (LIKE %searchterm1%)
  OR (LIKE %searchterm2%)
  OR (LIKE %searchterm3%) ....
```

Comment: You want Full-Text Search. Google it. Please also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009208/mysql-fulltext-search-in-php-using-string-contaning-keywords

Comment: I think it would be easier to use regexp to manage such problems

Answer (score 0):

Try This. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE SEARCH 
REGEXP  'searchterm1|searchterm2|searchterm3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a SQL SELECT statement that uses the LIKE comparison operator

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.col LIKE CONCAT('%','cdef','%') 
   AND t.col LIKE CONCAT('%','hijk','%')
   AND t.col LIKE CONCAT('%','mnop','%')
```

Only rows that have a value in the `col` column that contains all of the strings `'cdef'`, `'hijk'`, and `'mnop'` will be returned.

---

You specifically asked about the `LIKE` comparison operator. There's also a `REGEXP` operator that matches regular expressions.  And the Full-Text search feature may be a good fit your use case.