# Compare strings of text between two tables in a database or locally

Tags: mysql, sql, solr, full-text-search, sphinx

**Edit**: SQL doesn't work for this. I just found out about Solr/Sphinx and it seems like the right tool for this problem, so if you know Solr or Sphinx I'm eager to hear from you.

Basically, I have a .tsv with patent info and a .csv with product names. I need to match each row of the patents column against the product names and extract the occurrences in a new .csv column.

You can scroll down and see the example at the end.

*Original question:*

SQL newbie here so bear with me :). I can't figure out how to do this:

My database:

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_prodpatdb   |
+-----------------------+
| assignee              |
| patents               |
| patent_info           |
| products              |
+-----------------------+
mysql> DESCRIBE patents;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ...         |             |      |     |         |       |
| patent_id   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| text        | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ...         |             |      |     |         |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> DESCRIBE products;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name        | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have to work with the columns `name` and `text`, they look like this:

```
name
product1
product2
product3
...
~10M rows
```

---

```
text
long text description 1
long text description 2
long text description 3
...
~88M rows
```

I need to check `patents.text` row 1 and match it against `products.name` column to find every product name in that row, then store those products names in a new table. Then check row 2 and repeat.

If a `patents.text` row has a product name several times only copy it to the new table once. If some row has no product names just skip it. The output should be something like this:

```
Operation  Product
1          prod5, prod6
2          prod7
...
```

An example:

```
name
valve
a/c fan
farmed salmon
...
```

---

```
  text
  This patent deals with a new approach to air-conditioned fan. With some new valve the a/c fan is 
so much better. The new valve is great.
  This patent has no product names in it.
  This patent talks about farmed salmon.
  ...
```

---

Desired output:

```
Operation   Product
1           valve, a/c fan
2           farmed salmon
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` with inner `SELECT` query, e.g.:

```
SELECT p.text, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM products WHERE LOCATE(LOWER(name), LOWER(p.text)) > 0) AS 'products' 
FROM patent p;
```

Comment: The workbench report a missing closing parenthesis syntax error for the `(SELECT`. Maybe it's a bug for subqueries using multiple parenthesis? Because the code seems fine.

Comment: there is no comma after `p.text,` in your query

Comment: oops stupid mistake, sorry, run your code now but returns `Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row` after a while. In any case, a full-text search is maybe better as suggested above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499438/mysql-like-vs-locate not sure this would be faster; but good idea to try.

Comment: @DarshanMehta I run your code for 21 hours. It was _running_ for 1159 seconds and the rest of the time _fetching_. I stopped it because I'm trying to do this with Solr, I think that is a more rational approach than with RDBMS for what I need. Thanks a lot for your help! I'll answer  the question when I manage to solve it.

Comment: Well, it's difficult to get the bigger picture from one question and a couple of example records, but yes, if the tables contain millions of blob rows then `MySQL` is not the best technology to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see doing this with a reasonable performance is a full text search.  I've seldom done these myself (maybe 3 times in 20+ years now); so I'll defer to someone else w/ more experience.

Using https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html as a starting point.

Provided the full text index has been created, it may be something as simple as:

```
SELECT pat.patent_ID, group_concat(P.Name)  
FROM patents pat 
CROSS JOIN products p 
WHERE MATCH (pat.text)
        AGAINST (p.name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
GROUP BY pat.patent_ID;
```

Since every product vs every patent we have to cross join so we now have 880 million rows; that alone is a a lot.  The more reading I do on this however, the more I realize we're dealing with unstructured data in a RDBMS. By its nature that's not an ideal fit; and there may be much more optimized methods to handle this outside of a RDBMS, or we have to spend the time to structure the data in the RDBMS so it can be more effective with the indexes (such as splitting the text into it's own rows per word for indexing)

Lastly, do we really need to look for ALL products? the sheer size of the data involved on both sizes means this is going to take time in a database that doesn't handle unstructured data well.

### Edit

Scratch the below as it will not be able to handle the load effectively. But keeping it for posterity.

I think `concat()` and `group_concat()` may do the trick.

We join where the patent.text is like the product name generating multiple rows.  the group_concat then combines these rows into one record.  I'm not sure where "Operation" comes from in your result.

```
SELECT pat.text, group_concat(P.Name) as Product
FROM patents pat
INNER JOIN text
 on pat.text like concat('%',p.name,'%')
GROUP by pat.text
```

However don't expect this to be fast; as we're doing a wild card search using a % on both ends; so no index can be used.

Comment: Operation 1 is when you read `patents.text` row 1, operation 2 when you read the next row with a product name in it, etc. Thanks for the answer I will try this. One question, how do you save the output in another column or table?

Comment: Nvm, is this part of your code right? `as Product` :)

Comment: It's been running for 10 hours now and, unintentionally, I limited the number of rows returned by queries to 500 so maybe this is not feasible. If  it takes 1 minute to read every `patents.text` row, *88M rows, that's 61k days xD T.T

Comment: A full text search is likely going to be faster. Knowing the table size.I don't do them often so I would have to look up the settings and process.

Comment: mmm thanks for the info, i'm reading [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) but I don't see how to make MATCH() look row by row instead of the whole column.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question match() goes row by row and returns all records which contain any part of a match against the desired column. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009208/mysql-fulltext-search-in-php-using-string-contaning-keywords  this uses boolean mode to return a 1 or zero where as the natural mode returns a value based on a weighted relevance of match between zero and 1 I believe.  I can't see a silver bullet here as the volume of data and the needed to search multiple times all patents for words will take time.

Comment: What actually may be fastest is breaking apart the patents table into separate rows for each word maintaining the patent_ID .  index the words table and then a straight join. This does assume each product is a single word however.  if that's not the case, then the only way I'm familiar with simply takes too long; and the full text search seems plausible but again given volume of data, I don't know how effective this would be.  I did miss the original # of rows involved here; had I noticed that I'm not sure I would have suggested the like %product%.

Comment: Rather than re-invent the wheel... https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118759/how-to-quickly-search-through-a-very-large-list-of-strings-records-on-a-databa

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql SolR is an alternative to Sphinx.  Simply put I think we've hit a technology limit with mySQL.

Comment: I've looked both and I think i'm going to give Solr a try. Thanks a LOT for your help @xQbert :)

Comment: by the way, unfortunately, AGAINST only takes a string or a variable containing a string as an argument, so it should be something like '%products.name%'